# Redirecting a request in a routing constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, cancan, sidekiq, cancancan

I have Sidekiq mounted in my routes file to the `/sidekiq` endpoint.

I use a `constraints` option to have it call an external class for validation as a way of preventing non-privelaged users from accessing that endpoint.

```
# config/routes.rb
mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq", constraints: Sidekiq::AdminConstraint.new

# lib/sidekiq/admin_constraint.rb
module Sidekiq
  class AdminConstraint
    def matches?(request)
      return false unless request.session[:user_id]
      user = User.find_by_id(request.session[:user_id])
      user && Ability.new(user).can?(:manage, :sidekiq)
    end
  end
end
```

This setup works great. However, it only lets me return `true` / `false` on whether the request should go through or not. It does not let me -

1. Set a flash message (e.g. "You are not permitted to access that page") and
2. Redirect to some arbitrary page

In that sense, I'm looking for it to behave more like a controller's `before_filter`.

Is there a way I can modify the `request` object that's passed in to implement that redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: This answer was helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649787/718180

Answer (score 1):

I don't have idea directly set the flash messages, But we can use in different way.

Use the following solution

In your `routes.rb`, add the following line in the end of the file

```rb
match "*path", :to => "application#error_404"
```

This basically means, any path that is not defined in your route will end up going to `error_404` in `application_controller`. Its very important to put this at the end of your file

And in your `ApplicationController`, add

```rb
def error_404
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Thanks